# Bootstrap Alert in Jumbotron wrong margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I am creating a part of my website which includes a Jumbotron and a collapsable alert message, both from the Bootstrap Framework. I am having problems with the margins from the alert box. I use the standard CSS for the Jumbotron with adjusted paddings, which do not interfere with my problem though.

This is how it looks like unmodified: [image]

I want the alert box to fit with the alignment of the selection boxes. I tried override the properties of the alert class with this:

```
.alert-custom-style {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The result of it is here: [image]

This does work fine for the left side, but the margin-right property somehow does not get considered. I tested this by putting margin-left back to 0px but then it just looked like in the first picture. I am really scratching my head around why the left margin property works, but not the right one. Any suggestions or help is very appreciated.

Here is the HTML-Code:

```
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-custom">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-buffer">
                    <!-- Dropdown List for the first country -->
                    <select id="country1" name="Country Selection 1" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true" title="Choose..."></select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-buffer">
                    <!-- Compare Button -->
                    <button id="btnSubmit" type="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Compare</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-buffer">
                    <!-- Dropdown List for the second country -->
                    <select id="country2" name="Country Selection 2" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true" title="Choose..."></select>
                </div>

                <!-- JavaScript file to handle the data management -->
                <script src="js/compare.js"></script>
                <!-- JavaScript file to handle the selection lists -->
                <script src="js/lists.js"></script>
            </div>

            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div id="alert" class="collapse alert alert-custom-style col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="alert"> <!-- Collapsed by default -->
                    <strong>Warning: </strong><span id="alert-span">Please select at least two different countries</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Edited the post @ZimSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For row that holds the alert with the class `top-buffer` try adding:

```
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
```

I don't have all your css, but here is a rough version that I think approximates what you want.

Use the "full page" button at the bottom of the snippet to see the result in a wider view.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-buffer">
        <!-- Dropdown List for the first country -->
        <select id="country1" name="Country Selection 1" class="selectpicker" style="width:100%;" data-width="100%" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true" title="Choose...">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-buffer">
        <!-- Compare Button -->
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="width:100%;">
          Compare
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-buffer">
        <!-- Dropdown List for the second country -->
        <select id="country2" name="Country Selection 2" class="selectpicker" style="width:100%;" data-width="100%" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true" title="Choose...">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="row top-buffer" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">
      <div id="alert" class="collapse in alert alert-custom-style col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="alert" style="background-color: red;"> <!-- Collapsed by default -->
        <strong>Warning: </strong><span id="alert-span">Please select at least two different countries</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This actually helped, only that it was now correct on the right side and had a 30px margin on the left side, I almost cried. I then tried around a bit and came up with a solution: I put the `style="margin-right: 15px"` in the div object and the `style="margin-left: 15px"` in the div object for the alert. I also removed the custom alert class. It worked. Please do not ask how or why this works. Like, ever. Just don't.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I'm looking at this again and realizing the other answer to this issue was to put the alert into a column. That was really the culprit as far as why the row with the select inputs had different margins and padding to the row with the alert and no column. Good luck with it all.